# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fillna' Error

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting an error in the following code. Not able to understand why. Getting an error at the last line of the code. Please advise what has to be done to correct it. In addition to this df.isna().any() is also not working.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

data = pd.read_csv('BlackFriday.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.info()
df.describe()
df.head()

#To check the unique values of Product Categories 2, 3 and then assign a default value accordingly for NaN's

Product_Category_2 = df['Product_Category_2'].unique()
Product_Category_3 = df['Product_Category_3'].unique()
print('Product_Category_2', Product_Category_2)
print('Product_Category_3', Product_Category_3)

df = df.fillna(0, inplace=True)




---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-7f28e582ea84> in <module>()
      1 #We can replace the NaN's with 0.
----> 2 df = df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
      3 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fillna'
```

Comment: First issue I see, `pd.read_csv` already creates a dataframe, so you don;t then need to assign it to a dataframe again. Then, you can't use both `inplace=True` and `df=df.fillna()` in the same assignment operation. `inplace=True` causes the `fillna` method to return `None`, which you then assign to `df`. That works, and assigns your variable to `None`, but should not cause the error you're seeing unless you attempt to re-run that line of code or reference the dataframe after running it.

Comment: Thankyou I got my mistake about the double data frame assigned. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I've moved my comment to an answer and added detail, feel free to accept it if you feel it helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First issue I see, `pd.read_csv` already creates a dataframe, so you don't then need to assign it to a dataframe again.

Then, your primary issue: You can't use both `inplace=True` and `df=df.fillna()` in the same assignment operation. `inplace=True` causes the `fillna` method to return `None`, which you then assign to df. That works, and assigns your variable to `None`, but should not cause the error you're seeing unless you attempt to re-run that line of code or reference the dataframe after running it.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,0],'c':[None,None,1,2,None]})

    a   b   c
0   1   6   NaN
1   2   7   NaN
2   3   8   1.0
3   4   9   2.0
4   5   0   NaN
```

Correct:

Either

```
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

OR

```
df=df.fillna(0)
df
    a   b   c
0   1   6   0.0
1   2   7   0.0
2   3   8   1.0
3   4   9   2.0
4   5   0   0.0
```

Incorrect:

```
df=df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

print(df)
None
```